# Create a loop of a loop from same list in java

Tags: java

I have an array of data being recieved from an endpoint in spring boot. Here is a sample of the data:

```
[
  {
    "sales_id": 1,
    "user_id": 12,
    "orders": {
      "order_id": 109,
      "total_amount": 57190
    }
  },
  {
    "sales_id": 2,
    "user_id": 10,
    "orders": {
      "order_id": 125,
      "total_amount": 57600
    }
  }
]
```

These are the models used:

```
// Sales.java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Sales {
    private long sales_id;
    private long user_id;
    private Orders orders;
}


// Orders.java
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Orders {
    private Long order_id;
    private Double total_amount;
}
```

I want to add all the `total_amount` belonging to each user (`user_id`) and save this to a table with these columns (`amount` and `user_id`). So I need to iterate over the list and grab all the sales that belong to each user then add these together and save them. So far I have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allSales.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(allSales.get(i).getOrders().getTotal_amount());
    System.out.println(allSales.get(i).getUser_id());
    // What goes here?
}
```

I think I'm supposed to use two for-loops but I cannot get myself to come up with this logic. Please help.

Comment: Depends on what exactly you need but using a map might be a good start. It could be a `Map<Long, Double>` where the key is the user id and the value is the total amount, a `Map<Long, List<Sales>>` to collect the sales per user id or maybe a `Map<Long, List<Orders>>` to just collect the orders. In the latter 2 cases you might need an additional loop to get the totals or you do it in 1 loop and either maintain a map that contains something like `UserSales` (which then contains the sales for one user) or 2 maps.

Comment: Btw, the name `orders` in the json would normally indicate that you _might_ receive more than one order per sale. If this isn't the case then renaming this to `order` would make it easier to understand. If there could be more than 1 order per sale, then this ideally should always be an array so you don't have to handle 2 different cases (1 order vs. multiple orders).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To any one with the same issue:

```
    Map<Long, Pair<Long, Double>> totalAmountPerUser = new HashMap<>();

    for (Sales salesData : allSales) {
        long salesId = salesData.getSales_id();
        long userId = salesData.getUser_id();
        Double orderTotalAmount = salesData.getOrders().getTotal_amount();

        totalAmountPerUser.put(userId,
                new Pair<>(salesId, totalAmountPerUser.getOrDefault(userId, new Pair<>((long) 0, (double) 0)).getSecond() + orderTotalAmount));
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Long, Pair<Long, Double>> entry : totalAmountPerUser.entrySet()) {
        try {
            jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_SAVE_DATA, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getFirst(), entry.getValue().getSecond());
        } catch (Exception error) {
            throw new EtAuthException("Unable to save sales: " + error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have hashMap or Map in list , and for get the Value , you must use 2 loop ,
try this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < allSales.size(); i++) { 
  for (Sales j: allSales.size.get(i).values){
    System.out.println(j.toString());
 }  }
```